# Questions about @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring

I have a couple questions about @PostConstruct in Spring.

1. @PostConstruct is thread safe?
2. Does this open a new thread for the init method or how it works?

I will be grateful for the answers)

Comment: You must be more specific about what you mean by "thread safe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, Spring calls `@PostConstruct` marked methods the object before it gets available to the application (Before injection). This is a part of bean creation.
2. No. Spring creates an internal structure called "bean definition" during the application context initialization. Its a meta data about the bean. If the bean has "post-construct" method spring knows this and calls the relevant method during the bean creation.

Answer (score 0):

@PostConstruct is thread safe. It only runs once after the bean created in the whole lifecycle of the bean.

Comment: Any source to back this up? Based on observation, I guess this is true. 

Tried looking through the docs but as far as i hve search there does not seem to be any mentions of this.